# How to create a common Header or Footer in NodeJS with Express without using templating engine like hbs or ejs

Tags: node.js, express

I want create common header(navbar) and footer page to be included in multipage/several page of website. Create dynamic Website using nodejs and expressjs

Putting code for navbar and footer in common header.html and footer.html and call or include this common header/navbar and footer html page in other html pages.

I want to do this without templating engine like hbs or ejs for website creation using Nodejs and expressJs in simple html file.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps you can follow to create a common header/navbar and footer for your website using Node.js and Express.js without a templating engine:

1. Create two new folders named "public" and "views" in the root directory of your project.
2. Inside the "public" folder, create two new files named "header.html" and "footer.html". These files will contain the HTML code for your common header/navbar and footer.
3. Inside the "views" folder, create a new HTML file for each page of your website.
4. In each of the HTML files you want to include the common header/navbar and footer, add the following code at the top and bottom of the file.

```
<!--#include virtual="../public/header.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="../public/footer.html" -->
```

Note: the above code uses SSI (Server Side Include) syntax to include the header and footer files as static HTML, which is supported by Express.js.
In your Express.js app, add the following two lines of code to enable SSI:

```
const SSI = require('express-ssi');
app.use(SSI({
  baseDir: __dirname + '/views', // The directory where HTML files are stored
  ext: '.html' // The file extension of HTML files
}));
```

That's it!

Comment: But why you comment these two    <!--#include virtual="../public/header.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="../public/footer.html" -->

Comment: Just follow your steps one after another, but point number 4 is little bit confusing. Is this way to write the same code in our index.html file <!--#include virtual="../public/header.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="../public/footer.html" --> if yes then why you comment

Comment: In order for those lines to be processed as SSI (Server Side Include) directives by the web server, they need to be commented out using <!-- -->

Comment: Read this if you want to find more information.
https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/itsnew/web/ssi

Comment: ChatGPT answers are not allowed!

Comment: You didnt even read the docs... Thats what you posted is in any way wrong!

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create a layout for your application and you can do that by using layouts

```js
app.use(expressLayouts);
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts

find out more on this website.